# Why does queryPurchaseHistoryAsync not work with promo codes?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, android-inapp-purchase

I have been only using `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync` for in-app purchases on Android and it has been working fine. After using a promo code I noticed that it is not seen by my code. Is there a reason for this? Normally this function should return all recent purchases and redeeming code is a recent purchase. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide the sample code of your it would be more helpful for more to find you a solution

At the same time  hope this [link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_promo#support_promo_codes_in_your_app) provide more information to Support promo codes in your app

which version of the google play billing api you are  on, from the method name, he should be on the new one 
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview